# HTML5 Audio Plays Randomly

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am implementing sound effects in HTML5 audio but after a while, it just stops playing any audio. The file type is correct because it starts fine but then seems to give up.

```
var sound = new Audio(url);
function play() {        
    sound.play();
}
```

Is there a better way to do this so it consistently plays sound?

Here is a link to my implementation. Easy to reproduce by pressing spacebar a lot until it eventually gives up (also shoot the lights for added sounds). http://craftyjs.com/elevatoraction/

This occurs for me in the latest version of Chrome (8.0)

**Edit:** I did as Gaurav suggested and only played the same instance of each sound file, but the same sort of problems are present. It will arbitrarily stop playing.

**Edit 2:** I just noticed that whenever I try to play the sound, the `networkState` is always `1` which according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDOMHTMLMediaElement) means it hasn't fully loaded. That is odd seeing as it still plays sometimes and even when it plays the `networkState` is always `1`

Comment: You should specify what browser version(s) and operating system version(s) you've reproduced the problem on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't create a new audio object each time you want to play a sound, reuse the same resource.

```
var sound1 = new Audio(url);
function playSound1() {
    sound1.play();
}
```

I think this is related to the bug http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=57070

Comment: Oh so it is a bug. How would I would play the same sounds at the same time though?

Comment: Well then you do have to use multiple audio objects. And you'll have to manage them so you create the minimum number you actually need. Until the bug is fixed, anyway.

Comment: Sounds good. Does that mean I have to create about 2 or 3 audio objects of each file and check which ones are playing. I'm finding it hard to get good documentation to be honest.

Comment: @Louis correct. I'm writing a library for this, and the method I use (for speed), is to have 2 lists, one for the objects themselves, another for the free objects. Basically you have to get the first item of the free object list, remove it from the list, then play it. Add an onended callback that will add it back to the list once it's done. Of course, if there are no free sounds, you can just create a new `Audio` object.